# Error while running 'tns doctor'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have successfully completed the setup for nativescript without getting any errors or issues. But when I test my install for nativescript using `tns doctor` I am getting an error something like this.[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered running the setup using the console as Administrator?

Comment: Only the lines displayed in red do not come this time. Rest all is the same

Comment: @pkanev When I try to run `tns run android` in my projects dir the error comes. `The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.`

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Environment variables are not set.
Taken from Documentation.

set ANDROID_HOME=installation location \android-sdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools